# Newton's method convergence implementation

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

How can I solwe this problem:

Experimentaly examine convergence Newton's method for conformation:

\begin{align}
2x^3-y^2-1=0 \\
xy^3-y-4=0
\end{align}
for various loaded inputs with start points $(x_0,y_0)$.

If someone could help matemathically or give a clue how to implement that.

Comment: Please check if the edited question still represents what you where asking for. Which programming language are you preferring?

Comment: see here http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/tools/tools23.html

Comment: Did you search for *newton's method for a system + name* of software in which you are supposed to implement it?

Comment: @sonystatmap probably i would pick c#

Answer (score 4):

I am going to jump start you, but you need to show some work.

The regular Newton-Raphson method is initialized with a starting point $x_0$ and then you iterate $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$$

In higher dimensions, there is an exact analog. We define:

$$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x, y) \\  f_2(x, y)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 x^3 - y^2 - 1 \\   x y^3 - y - 4  \end{bmatrix}$$

The derivative of this system is the Jacobian given by:

$$J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6x^2 & -2y \\ y^3 & 3xy^2 - 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

The function $G$ is defined as:

$$G(x) = x - J(x)^{-1}F(x)$$

and the functional Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear systems is given by the iteration procedure that evolves from selecting an initial $x^{(0)}$ and generating for $k \ge 1$,

$$x^{(k)} = G(x^{(k-1)}) = x^{(k-1)} - J(x^{(k-1)})^{-1}F(x^{(k-1)}).$$

We can write this as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x^{(k)}\\y^{(k)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(k-1)}\\y^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}w_1^{(k-1)}\\w_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}$$

where:

$$\begin{bmatrix}w_1^{(k-1)}\\w_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}= -\left(J\left(x^{(k-1)},y^{(k-1)}\right)\right)^{-1}F\left(x^{(k-1)},y^{(k-1)}\right)$$

Here is a starting vector:

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(0)}\\y^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

You should end up with a solution that looks something like:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.234274 \\ 1.661526  \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, for a different starting vector you are going to get a different solution and perhaps no solution at all.

Experimenting, there was definitely a radius where things work as expected, but as soon as you get away from those initial points, the method does not work (converges to wrong solution).